# Problem producing a pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, multicol, pgf-pie

I tried producing a pie chart with `pgf-pie` (which seemed easy to me), but it was not available on my system and on MiKTex. So I tried this unsuccessfully. Kindly help.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{datapie}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{filecontents}{institutes.csv}
Name,Quantity
"ERD", 50
"NERD",50
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{population.csv}
Name,Quantity
"ERD", 30
"NERD", 70
\end{filecontents}

\DTLloaddb{institute}{institutes.csv}
\DTLloaddb{population}{population.csv}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Are all the gastroesophageal reflux disease patients same? }
\begin{exampleblock}
{All patients present with  heart burn \texttt{and/or} regurgitation of sour fluid in mouth }So all these patients are same with varying severity of symptoms?
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{itemize}
\item upper gastro-intestinal endoscopy 
\item 24 hour Ph-metry 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Endoscopy Data}
\begin{columns}[2]
\begin{column}[0.4\textwidth]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\DTLpiechart{variable=\quantity,outerlabel=\name}{institute}{%
\name=Name,\quantity=Quantity}
\caption{A pie chart} 
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[0.4\textwidth]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\DTLpiechart{variable=\quantity,outerlabel=\name}{population}{%
\name=Name,\quantity=Quantity}
\caption{A pie chart}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need a pie chart to display a 50-50 distribution?  Maybe you could just say that in a sentence instead? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `beamer` syntax errors, so this isn't really related to the pie-charts at all:

- `\begin{columns}[2]`: there is no optional argument `2` for `columns`, you don't have to specify the number of columns, if that is what you wanted. Just remove `[2]`.
- `\begin{column}[0.4\textwidth]`: the width of a column is a mandatory argument, and has to placed in braces, not brackets. Hence, write `\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}` instead.

Note that `beamer`s `columns` are *not* related to the `multicol` package, they are defined by the document class itself, so you don't actually need that package for this example.

---

If you want to use `pgf-pie` you have to download `pgf-pie.sty` from https://code.google.com/p/pgf-pie/ and make it available for use. The quickest way is to  place it in the same folder as your `.tex` file.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How can I rotate the pie chart so that the one with 50, 50 distribution is vertically divided and not horizontal

Comment: @user34083 No idea, I'd ask a new question about that.